# iOS screen recording - enable Safari audio?

Tags: ios, webkit, mobile-safari, audio-recording

I'm making screen recordings of an in-house web app, using iOS Safari and the built-in iOS screen recorder.  No audio is recorded.  If I enable microphone recording, the audio is recorded but poorly and mixed with room sound (likely recording the device's speaker).  The same is true of native apps with WKWebViews.

I'm curious what's happening here.  Is Safari/Webkit actively blocking audio recording?  Is there a Javascript or Webkit instruction to enable audio recording?

Note that I'm not trying to get around any protection from recording commercial videos, just sounds generated from my own site/app, in order to make promotional videos.  So changes made within my app or web site are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Disable microphone audio and connect the device to an external audio source (e.g. headphones).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of various hardware workarounds (my favorite thus far is connecting to a Mac via lightning cable and using Quicktime Player).  I'm interested in the software mechanics behind the scenes.

Comment: @MitchCohen could you elaborate on that Quicktime technique?

Comment: never mind. found it here: https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/03/26/tip-record-your-ipads-screen-on-your-mac-with-quicktime-player